# Domain Registrar Reseller Won't Provide EPP for Transfer

Tags: domain, domain-registrar

I've been using Arvixe for my hosting and domain registrar business for the last few years but their customer service has cratered and I am out of patience and eager to make a change (of both web host and registrar - I want no part of Arvixe anymore).  My problem: Arvixe will not send me the EPP code necessary to transfer my domain.  I've tried everything - their web interface, phone calls, support chat, opening tickets, email..  no result.  I'll get a boilerplate response that they 'just sent it' or that 'they are investigating' and that's where it ends.  My last four inquiries have gotten no response from them at all.  I have confirmed that the email address on the domain is correct in WHOIS and that it isn't spam-blocked.

The WHOIS record for my domain lists the registrar as ENOM LLC.  I contacted ENOM four days ago and just a reply that Arvixe is a reseller of theirs and that I must deal with Arvixe to resolve this.  Arvixe is a non-responsive black hole.  What can I do?  Has anyone ever encountered this?  Does ENOM as the registrar of record in WHOIS have any obligations to this at all?  I feel like my domain has checked into the Hotel California.

Any suggestions (diplomatic or brute force - at this point I'm prepared to go to war) would be enormously appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Rick

Comment: I once went to the organisation who organised domain names for the .co.uk suffix to get my domain name from an unhelpful registrar ( http://www.discountdomainsuk.com/ ). It took a little time but it worked. Basically, go above Enom.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  It took a follow-up but eNom came through.  They're ICANN accredited so there was some necessity for them to hook me up.

Comment: There is no way out. You need to contact ENOM directly so you can transfer your domain. I believe that you dont need to transfer your domain. ENOM and Arvixe are different. Just stop using Arvixe hosting and then you can keep your domain with ENOM. Just make sure you have your domain login details.

Comment: Thanks Douglas.  It took a few pushes but eNOM finally got it done.  Up and gone from Arvixe.  Decided to give Google Domains a try for my registrar.

Comment: Having same problem, and Arvixe keep sending invalid EPP code.

Answer (score 2):

Escalate the issue to the registry involved if the registrar is not responding. Whatever they are saying (about resellers) they, as registrar, are responsible for your domain at the registry.

And for gTLDs, you have an ICANN policy that takes care of such problems, please have a look at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/auth-2013-05-03-en